# I want to remove specific rows and restart the values from 1

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time Value
  1     5
  2     3
  3     3
  4     2 
  5     1
```

I want to remove the first two rows and then restart time from 1. The dataframe should then look like:

```
Time Value
  1     3
  2     2 
  3     1
```

I attach the code:

```
 file = pd.read_excel(r'C:......xlsx')


 df = file0.loc[(file0['Time']>2) & (file0['Time']<11)]

 df = df.reset_index()
```

Now what I get is:

```
 index  Time Value
0      3     3
1      4     2 
2      5     1
```

Thank you!

Comment: `df.Time = df.Time - 2` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.loc[]` accessor and `reset_index()` method:

```
df=df.loc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally use list comprehension:

```
df['Time']=[x for x in range(1,len(df)+1)]
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    Time    Value
0   1       3
1   2       2
2   3       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use df.loc to extract the subset of dataframe, Reset the index and then change the value of Time column.

```
df = df.loc[2:].reset_index(drop=True)
df['Time'] = df.index + 1
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways to do that.

first :

```
df[2:].assign(time = df.time.values[:-2])
```

Which returns your desired output.

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

second :

```
df = df.set_index('time')
df['value'] = df['value'].shift(-2)
df.dropna()
```

this return your output too but turn the numbers to float64

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.0 |
| 2 | 2.0 |
| 3 | 1.0 |